# JSP hidden field produces null in servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, null, hidden

I have a hidden field in a form whose value is set by javascript. I have confirmed that the value indeed gets set. However, when I try to send it to a servlet, it produces a null value. I do submit to the servlet using the POST method and with a "submit" button. The value is obtained by user input in the "qtyText" textbox. In the JS its value gets dynamically set. Why would it not get sent to the servlet?
JS

```
   function(calculateTotalPrice(txtbxvalue, price)
  {
   myForm = document.forms[0];        
      var txtBx = myForm.elements['qtyText'];
      var txtBxHidden = myForm.elements['qtyTextHidden'];
      for(var i = 0; i < txtBx.length; i++) 
         {
          var curTxtBx = txtBx[i].value; 
          var txtBxHiddenBx = txtBxHidden[i];
           txtBxHiddenBx.value = curTxtBx;
         }
   }
```

HTML

```
<table>

   <c:forEach items="${ListInServlet}" var= "exBean">
  <form name = "tableForm" method = "post" action= "/rpsapp/someservlet">
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value= "<c:out Value 
                                          = "${exBean.productId}"/>"  />
         <input type="hidden"  value = "somevalue" name="qtyTextHidden"/>
         <input name = "qtyText" type = "textbox" size = "2" value = "" onChange 
                              = "calculateTotalPrice(this, '${exBean.price}')"/>

   </c:forEach>
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: how do you retrieve the value in servlet?

Comment: String qty = request.getParameter("qtyTextHidden");

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach statement (tag) is overlapping with form tag.

You need to either have this format:

```
<c:forEach ...> <form ...> ... </form> </c:forEach>
```

Comment: How do we rectify that? I know that its not perfectly in order. There is another submit button in there. But does that cause the value to not be passed on to the servlet? There are other two values(one hidden, and another "select" which go to the servlet without issues.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but your form opening/closing tags should match and your submit button should be inside form

Comment: @Raghu Without knowing what your current code looks like it's impossible to help. Your previous code created multiple forms, only one of which would be submitted at a time

Comment: The issue is , only the hidden field for which the user input is the value is not being submitted, but other fields do. I have the entire code here JSFiddle               http://jsfiddle.net/raghujoshi/yBJJJ/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create hidden variables as many as you have products.

```
  <form name = "tableForm" method = "post" action= "/rpsapp/someservlet">
   <c:forEach items="${ListInServlet}" var= "exBean">
    <input type="hidden" name="productId${exBean.productId}" value= "<c:out Value 
                                          = "${exBean.productId}"/>"  />
         <input type="hidden"  value = "somevalue" name="qtyTextHidden${exBean.productId}"/>
         <input name = "qtyText${exBean.productId}" type = "textbox" size = "2" value = "" onChange 
                              = "calculateTotalPrice(this, '${exBean.price}')"/>

   </c:forEach>
  </form>
```

Comment: The issue is , only the hidden field for which the user input is the value is not being submitted, but other fields do. I have the entire code here JSFiddle jsfiddle.net/raghujoshi/yBJJJ